# Mobile Device Manager 2008 SP1 With WSUS 3.1 SP2

Tags: windows-server-2008

Can I install MDM 2008 SP1 with WSUS 3.1 SP2?

It fails telling me I need WSUS 3.0 SP1 or higher.. but since I have SP2 shouldn't it work?

I'm installing on Server 2008

Answer (score 1):

If the package is an MSI, you can use [Orca from Microsoft](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/255905) to modify the MSI to remove this restriction.

Whether or not this is wise in your scenario I don't know, as I don't know the technical situation behind it, but I've had this work fine for other programs where their pre-requisites didn't make sense.

Answer (score 0):

The latest released version of WSUS 3.0 is SP1 (http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/wsus/default.aspx), with SP2 in Beta... are you running the beta of SP2? If so, that's probably why the installer is choking.  Reverting to the latest released version should solve your problem.